# I haven't understood how does the line, $ H(Y)=-\int_D p(x)\log [\frac{1}{h}p(x)]dx$ appear?

Tags: calculus, probability

Let $X$ has a pdf $p(x)$.

let $$H(X)=-\int_D p(x)\log p(x)dx$$

where $D=[x:p(x)>0]$

And,

$Y=a+hX$ ; $-\infty<a<\infty$ , $h>0$

so $Y$  has the pdf  $g(x)=\frac{1}{h}p(\frac{x-a}{h})$

let $$H(Y)=-\int_{D_1} g(x)\log g(x)dx$$

where $D_1=[x:g(x)>0]$

$H(Y)=-\int_{D_1} g(x)\log g(x)dx$

$\Rightarrow H(Y)=-\int_{D_1} \frac{1}{h}p(\frac{x-a}{h})\log [\frac{1}{h}p(\frac{x-a}{h})]dx$

But i haven't understood how does the next line appear?

$\Rightarrow H(Y)=-\int_D p(x)\log [\frac{1}{h}p(x)]dx$ ?

Comment: It's substitution, baby!

Comment: @Raskolnikov Can you please show the steps? What is the new transformed variable and how to change the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformation is

$$u=\frac{x-a}{h}$$

The range of $u$ is $D$ if the range of $x$ is $D_1$. They just slightly abused notation by reusing $x$ instead of $u$.

Comment: How have you understood that  "The range of $u$ is $D$ if the range of $x$ is $D_1$"?

Comment: I've looked at the definitions of $D$ and $D_1$ and $g(x)$

Comment: $D_1=[x:g(x)>0]=[x:\frac{1}{h}p(\frac{x-a}{h})>0]=[x:\frac{x-a}{h}\epsilon D]$. Is this the process?

Comment: Yes, that's right.